# GNU Parallel on MacOS with Python annoying popup

Tags: macos, gnu-parallel

Whenever I run a Python script through GNU Parallel on MacOS, each Python instance appears and disappears in the dock. This would be fine, but it then de-selects whichever window I am working in as if I opened a new application. This makes it very annoying to have running in the background because text stops typing and quick look deactivates. For short scripts it makes the system unusable especially for typing.

Can I stop this behaviour either with `parallel` options or settings in MacOS?

Comment: I remember this used to annoy me but it doesn't happen on my mac anymore. I _think_ managing my python environments using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) stopped this behaviour, but I'm not sure (sorry).

Comment: I have no experience with this, and I do not see the issue on GNU/Linux. But maybe your version of Python connects to the GUI without needing to do so. Could you try `unset DISPLAY; parallel ...`?